# Visual Studio (SSDT) SSIS create new project issue

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server, visual-studio-2017, ssis

When I open Visual Studio SSDT click on new project for Integration Services Project then I get the following error..

Cannot load the component 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Database'.
Make sure that the product is installed properly.
 (Microsoft Visual Studio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just "fixed it".
I had to reinstall the Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Visual Studio 2017.

1. Uninstall the program:

   [image]
2. Download again the installer for data tools stand alone for 2017.
   This is [the link I used](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2095463).

Then I reopened my Integration Services Projects with Visual Studio Datatools and the error was gone.

Comment: Thanks its work just need to reinstall. and make sure dont update it else again same issue. :)